# Accessing the super from global scope

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There is a code in Objective C I'm trying to translate using mostly swift and that includes changing the isEqual: function to == operand. The problem is that the code asks me to check the super of the instances being compared but that's impossible from global scope where the operator functions are located.

Is there some other way to migrate this code to swift?

```
    - (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes *other = object;
    if (![super isEqual:other])
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is that the actual code you're trying to translate?

Comment: Luckily, this code does nothing beyond the superclass implementation...

Comment: Just remove the code, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the solution into 2 steps:

1) Define an extension of AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes where you override the isEqual method. (Here you can access the super).

```
extension AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes {
    public override func isEqual(object: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        // your custom logic will go here
        var other = object as AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes
        return super.isEqual(other)
    }
}
```

2) Overload the == operator simply calling the method defined above.

```
public func ==(lhs: AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes, rhs: AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqual(rhs)
}
```

Please note that I used the "public" modifier twice, they should be compatible with the access modifier of your class AAPLCollectionViewGridLayoutAttributes.